# Split/Explode a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, explode, preg-split

I need to split or explode a string.

```
K1123-Food, Apple, Z3456-Egg, Mushroom, M9902-Plant, Soil, Water, Q8876-Medicine, Car, Splitter
```

into something like

```
K1123-Food, Apple
Z3456-Egg, Mushroom
M9902-Plant, Soil, Water
Q8876-Medicine, Car, Splitter
```

Ideas on how to apply **preg_split** or **explode** will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The spacing between the commas can vary in the data string I am working with so this particular explode function will not work.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried yourself and the problems you have with it?

Comment: Well then probably `preg_split('/,\s+/', $string)`

Comment: @Nick ```preg_split('/,\s+/', $string);``` returns K1123-Food rather than K1123-Food, Apple and Z3456-Egg rather than Z3456-Egg, Mushroom

Comment: @NigelRen I am using the ```preg_match_all('~,(.*?)-~', $string, $output);``` approach but not quite there yet.

Comment: You added spaces that weren't in the original question...

Comment: You need to qualify the `, ` sequence with being followed by an uppercase character and digit e.g. `preg_split('/,\s+(?=[A-Z]\d)/', $string);`

Comment: @Nick Perfect! Works like charm.

Comment: Good to hear. On my phone so too hard to post as an answer.  Enjoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you, using `preg_match_all()`:

```php
$s = 'K1123-Food, Apple, Z3456-Egg, Mushroom, M9902-Plant, Soil, Water, Q8876-Medicine, Car, Splitter';
$pattern = '/(\w\d+-\w+(, [^\d]*))(, |$)/';
$matches = [];

preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

This outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => K1123-Food, Apple
    [1] => Z3456-Egg, Mushroom
    [2] => M9902-Plant, Soil, Water
    [3] => Q8876-Medicine, Car, Splitter
)
```

**OK so this is an advanced solution that tries to capture content mentioned by Toto:**

```php
$s = 'K1123-Food, Apple2, 123-456, Mushroom, Z3456-Egg, Mushroom, M9902-Plant, Soil, Water, Q8876-Medicine, Car, Splitter';
$pattern = '/([A-Z]\d+-\w+(.(?!([A-Z]\d))+)+)(, |$)/';
$matches = [];

preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => K1123-Food, Apple2, 123-456, Mushroom
    [1] => Z3456-Egg, Mushroom
    [2] => M9902-Plant, Soil, Water
    [3] => Q8876-Medicine, Car, Splitter
)
```

Keep in mind that it will never be possible to automatically and correctly put structure into otherwise unstructured content.
Every possible solution **will** make some assumptions about how your data really need to be structured.

Comment: Try it with `K1123-Food, Apple2, 123-456, Mushroom`

Comment: Yeah but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: How do you know there will never be digits in the string?

Comment: @Toto see my second solution.